# Principal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

A $G$-principal bundle $P\to M$ is commonly defined with a right action. Would it be possible to define it with a left action? Would it lead to contradictions?

Comment: What goes wrong with the usual game of letting $g$ act on the left by acting on the right by $g^{-1}$?

Comment: Well, I guess it is just the same, right? Namely that if I take a right action for $P$ and a left action for transition functions is the same as a left action for $P$ and a right action for transition functions? isn't it?